# Do these special substring sets form a matroid?

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, formal-languages, discrete-optimization, matroids

Let $S$ be a string.  Write $u \leqslant S$ to mean that $u$ is a substring.  Define $C_S = \{ u \leqslant S: |u| \geq 2 $ and $ u \alpha u \leqslant S $ for some $\alpha \leqslant S \}$.  Now let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all subsets $A \subset C_S$ such that there exists a decomposition $S = \sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_n$ and for all $u \in A$ either:

1. $\exists 1 \leq i \lt j \leq n$ such that $\sigma_i = u = \sigma_j$,
2. $\exists 1 \leq i \leq n$ such that $\sigma_i = u$ and $u \leqslant v \in A, $ for some $v \neq u$, or
3. $u \leqslant v \in A$ and $u \leqslant w \in A$ and $u,v,w$ are distinct.

I want to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a matroid.  I can easily show that any subset of $A$ is also of this form.  So what's left to prove is that if $B, A \in \mathcal{A}$, and $|B| \gt |A|$, then there exists $u \in B\setminus A$ such that $A \cup \{u\} \in \mathcal{A}$.

Can this be done by induction on the length of $S$?

---

Clearly, $\mathcal A$ is a matroid for $S = $ the empty string as it is just the trivial matroid  $\mathcal A = \{\varnothing\}$.

Now assume that it's true for all lengths $|S| = 0 \dots N$.  Then if we add a single symbol to $S$, say $a \in \Sigma'$, if $a$ is a new symbol not found in $S$, then we're done.  So assume that $a$ occurs in $S$.  Now, if no new elements to $C_S$ are created, ie. $C_S = C_{Sa}$ then we are similarly done.  Thus we only need to handle the case when a new element of $C_S$ is formed.

---

Application is to the smallest grammar problem.  I think I may have a greedy algorithm approach that might work.  And some algorithms are shown optimal this way (there are some theorems about greedoids).  So that's why it's interesting.

Comment: Hm, if $u \in A \subseteq C_S$ then the decomposition $\sigma_1 = \beta_0\; \sigma_2 = u;\; \sigma_3 = \alpha;\; \sigma_4 = u;\; \sigma_5 = \beta_1$ the condition (1) is satistisfied automatically. Then $\mathcal{A} = 2^{C_S}$, doesn't it? Did you mean that all (1), (2), (3) must be satisfied for $u \in A$?

Comment: @ArturRiazanov I think you mean $\mathcal A = 2^{C_S}$ ?

Comment: @ArturRiazanov this is carefully constructed, please expand more on what you mean since I'm not sure.  I do mean either-or.

Comment: @ArturRiazanov notice that for a *fixed decomposition into* $S = \sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_n$ and *for all* $u \in A$, either 1, 2, 3 must hold.  So it is not trivialized by your comment, though $\mathcal{A} = 2^{C_S}$ is a possibility in some instances.

Comment: Oh, ok, got it, thank you!

Comment: @ArturRiazanov added some info on an inductive approach.

Comment: @ArturRiazanov Found a way to prove it.  See below.  Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably less work to do induction on the size of $C_S$.  Now for $C_S = \{\}$ clearly $\mathcal{A} = \{\varnothing\}$ the trivial matroid.  So assume that it's true for $|C_S| = 1 \dots N$,  now if $C_S' = C_S \cup \{x\}$ is adding a new element define $\mathcal{A}' = \mathcal{A} \cup \{A \cup \{x\} : $ there is a decomposition $S=\sigma_1 \cdots x \sigma_k \cdots x\sigma_l \cdots \sigma_n$ and $\forall u \in A$ one of the following holds $\}$:

1. $\exists 1 \leq i \lt j \leq n : \sigma_i = u = \sigma_j$,
2. $\exists 1 \leq i \leq n : \sigma_i = u $ and $u \leqslant v \in A \cup \{x\}, u \neq v$, or
3. $u \leqslant v \in A\cup \{x\} $ and $u \leqslant w \in A\cup \{x\}, w \neq v$.

So that clearly $\mathcal{A}'$ is indeed the object we're set out to prove is a matroid.  We only need to show that if $A, B \in \mathcal{A}'$ and $|B| \gt |A|$ then there is $y \in B\setminus A$ such that $A\cup \{y\} \in \mathcal{A}'$.

But if $B', A' \in \mathcal{A}$, we're done by hypothesis.  So first assume that $B' \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A' \in \mathcal{A}' \setminus \mathcal{A}$.  Then $A' = A \cup \{x\}$ for some $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $|B'| \gt |A| = |A' \setminus \{x\}|$, so simply augment $A'$ and we're done.  Now if $B' \in \mathcal{A}'\setminus \mathcal{A}$ as well, say $B' = B \cup \{x\}$.  Then subtract $\{x\}$ from both $A'$ and $B'$ to get $|B| \gt |A|$ still!  Now since, both $A, B \in \mathcal{A}$ a known matroid, we are done!  $\square$